# How Does Ruby handle bytes/binary?

Tags: ruby, binary, byte

I'm trying to send a series of binary bytes across a socket, to meet a particular standard my company uses. No one in my company has used Ruby for this before, but in other languages, they send the data across one byte at a time, (usually with some sort of "pack" method).

I can't find anyway to create binary on the fly, or create bytes at all (the closest I can find it how you can turn a string into the bytes representing it's characters).

I know you can say something like :

@var = 0b101010101

But how would I convert a string in the form "101010101" or the resulting integer created when I do string.to_i(2) into an actual binary. If I just send the string accross a socket, won't that just send the ASCII for "0" and "1" instead of the literal characters?

Surely there is SOME way to do this natively in Ruby?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To make a string that has an arbitrary sequence of bytes, do something like this:

```
binary_string = "\xE5\xA5\xBD"
```

The "\x" is a special escape to encode an arbitrary byte from hex, so "\xE5" means byte 0xE5.

Then try sending that string on the socket.

Comment: Why there are some "/" in binary_string ?

Comment: It's quite possible for a binary string to have a byte with value 0x2F (47).  That's the ASCII encoding of "/" so if you `inspect` the string  Ruby will usually print out a "/".  The same thing goes for any ASCII character.  Ruby doesn't actually know if your string is a "binary string", to Ruby your string is basically a sequence of bytes (except in 1.9 they added some encoding information).

Answer (score 18):

Don't know if this helps enough, but you can index the bits in an integer in ruby.

```
n = 0b010101

n # => 21

n = 21

n[0]  # => 1
n[1]  # => 0
n[2]  # => 1
n[3]  # => 0
n[4]  # => 1
n[5]  # => 0
```

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at the [String.unpack](http://www.rubycentral.com/book/ref_c_string.html#String.unpack) method. This is an example:

```
str = "1010"
str.unpack("cccc")
=> [49, 48, 49, 48]
```

This will give you integer values. There are more ways to do the conversion.

Comment: Before this post was edited, it told me about Array.pack. I don't quite understand this. If I have:

@bob = ["111111111", "1000", "1111"] or whatever, and then I say:

@bob.unpack(b*), it displays something like: "/377"  Is that the correct binary? Isn't that only the first element of the array? How would I have it do the entire array?

Comment: Array.pack is the opposite of String.unpack. In your example bob.pack('b*') is only packing first element of array. You probably want bob.pack('b*b*b*'). However this is something different from what you are asking for in the question.