# Hbase shell - how to write byte value

Tags: hbase

I want to write a value say 65 in hbase.  I have to run the following command on hbase shell for that:

```
put 'table','key','cf:qual','A'
```

But is there a way to write it directly something like:

```
put 'table','key','cf:qual',65 (this is not allowed though)
```

Let me know if you understand the question else I will explain more.

Update:

By 65 I meant to put 'A' but directly the ascii value of 'A'. The real issue for me is I want to put values which fall in the range of 128-255 from the shell.

Comment: doesn't put 'table','key','cf:qual','65' puts 65 in the table?..if i am  understanding the question right..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since Hbase Shell is implemented using ruby, you can insert byte values by representing them in hexadecimal format.

**For example if you want to insert a byte value 255**

hex representation of 255 is FF.
In Hbase shell we should give it as stringBinary which is "\xFF"

The "\x" is a special escape character to encode an arbitrary byte from hex, so "\xFF" means byte 0xFF.

so `put 'table', 'rowkey', 'cf:qual', "\xFF"` will insert the byte 255

**Note**: The value has to be with in " " (double quotes) not ' ' (single quotes).

**Useful links:**

[How Does Ruby handle bytes/binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193853/how-does-ruby-handle-bytes-binary)

[Hexadecimal Digits (Hex-Codes) Cheatsheet](http://hex-codes.com/)

Comment: So how would one convert say \xFF to binary?

Comment: Please refer:
[hexadecimal to binary conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154783/hexadecimal-to-binary-conversion), 
[Conversion Table](https://ascii.cl/conversion.htm).
Hex is 4 bit long, so FF will be 1111 1111.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out shortly after posing the question.

Answer (score 7):

you can also use Hbase built in functions like this

```
> put 'table','rowkey','cf:qua', Bytes.toBytes(1234)
```

it works for me.

Comment: Correct approach for storing int

Comment: but no use for encoding a Long.