# "Escaped hexadecimal" to boolean

Tags: java, hbase

I'm working with HBase on a project and running into a seemingly simple situation that is throwing me for a loop. Hbase can store table values as escaped hexadecimal. In my case, I have true/false being stored as \x00 and \xFF, respectively.

The problem is (besides being unfamiliar with Java) I need to find a way to convert these to bool, or at least to compare them in a like-bool situation. They will never be anything other than \x00 and \xFF.

Is there not an elegant way to do this?

Please help, I'm really stuck.

Edit: This is probably relevant [Hbase shell - how to write byte value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22682308/hbase-shell-how-to-write-byte-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, apparently there is a Bytes.toBoolean() function.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you could do something like... Hex ->binary->boolean.

But there might even be a toBoolean method already.

Or you could override the compare method they're using. But this could yield undesirable effects.

Can you post the API for the class you're using?

Comment: I tried Hex->toBoolean, already. Let me try to convert to binary first.

Comment: Added a relevant link.

Comment: I don't think I can post the Java API.

Comment: I don&#39;t know about hbase in particular, or how to do this the _right_ way.

But making a static object that converts the thing you're getting to boolean would work.